# Is there a way to hide the Field List in an Excel PowerPivot table so that no users can see it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I've got a dashboard created via PowerPivot that, when the charts are selected, allows users to open the PowerPivot Field List, so they can see things like, for example, the email address of the survey respondents.

This is something I would like to hide fully - choosing "hide field list" by right-clicking the PivotTables that supply the data does not disable it in the Ribbon, where a user could still Hide/Show the field list. Does anyone know of a way to really, TRULY hide the field list from anyone to whom I might distribute this excel file? Screenshot attached. Thank you!

[Really I'm trying to permanently hide the entire box outlined in red, but in particular, the Email Address fields and stuff that identify people.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcPOJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I'm going to take the privacy defender role here:

If you really are worried about privacy issues, your first option should be to altogether remove the private information from the Excel sheet. If the personal data is in the document you share to others, they might get to see it somehow no matter what you try to do to hide it. I mean, they might be able to use a VBA macro or something even if the GUI wouldn't provide an easy way to see the data.

So, the question is the email address field needed in for the pivot table (or other parts of the sheet that are of interest to others) to work? If it is needed, the proper way would be to replace the email address with a anonymising key (e.g. a number) and move the other personal info that might be there to another document which is not shared, from where it is possible to fetch the personal information using the key IF that is needed. If the email address is not needed at all in the document you intend to share, just delete that from the data. Either way, you wouldn't need to try to hide anything from the users.